# Xval and Comparsion Operators?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xval

I read on the site that version 0.8 of xVal supports

"Support for comparison validators (e.g., “PasswordConfirm” must equal “Password”)"

Yet I see no tutorial on how to do this. I am trying to compare 2 passwords yet don't even know where to start.

Can someone show me how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of discussions on codeplex about comparison validators. One in January saying that is was not yet possible and then in June saying you can use custom validators.

January: [CompareTo Validation Attribute](http://xval.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=44786)

June: [How do I use the ComparisonRule when using DataAnnotations](http://xval.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=58597)

If nothing else it might point you in the right direction.